# Spring Boot with context failed to run with java -jar app.jar and not with spring-boot:run

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

My Spring Boot with context path /app is working when I run in using mvn spring-boot:run command but when I start using java -jar app.jar then it shows no explicit mapping error.

application.properties

```
server.servlet.context-path=/app
server.port=8080
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String contextPath() {
    return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that your main class (class annotated with @SpringBootApplication) is in a root package above other classes

When you run a Spring Boot Application, Spring will only scan the classes below your main class package.

**Example** - If your main class is in package com.spring.example, your controller class can be inside the package com.spring.example.controller (ie com.spring.example.*)

**How does this work ?**

@SpringBootApplication annotation 'wraps up' many other necessary annotations for the application to work. One such annotation is @ComponentScan annotation, which tells spring to look for components, but only in the sub packages.

From Spring Boot documentation:

> Many Spring Boot developers always have their main class annotated
> with @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan.
> Since these annotations are so frequently used together (especially if
> you follow the best practices above), Spring Boot provides a
> convenient @SpringBootApplication alternative.
>
> The @SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using
> @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan with their
> default attributes

**Can I override this default behavior and ask Spring to scan for Components in other packages ?**

Yes you can by using scanBasePackages.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.dao", "com.example.controller"})
```

Comment: I came up with a solution by packaging my application in war instead of jar and that fixed my problem.